# why does python display 0 when the result of calculation is less than 1?

Tags: python, variables, floating-point

i have the following code:

```
a = 0.0
b = 0.0
c = 1.0
while a < 300:
    a = a + 1
    b = b + 1
    c = c * b
    d = (3**a)
    e = (a+1)*c
    f = d / e
    print a, f
```

The moment f becomes less than 1, I get "0" displayed.. why?

Answer (score 1):

> The moment f becomes less than 1, I get "0" displayed

That's not what happens. The first time `f` is less than 1, `4.0 0.675` is printed. That's not `0`:

```
1.0 1.5
2.0 1.5
3.0 1.125
4.0 0.675
5.0 0.3375
```

The value of `f` then quickly becomes *very very small*, to the point Python starts using scientific notation negative exponents:

```
6.0 0.144642857143
7.0 0.0542410714286
8.0 0.0180803571429
9.0 0.00542410714286
10.0 0.00147930194805
11.0 0.000369825487013
12.0 8.53443431568e-05
13.0 1.82880735336e-05
14.0 3.65761470672e-06
15.0 6.8580275751e-07
```

Note the `-05`, `-06`, etc. The value of `f` has become so small that it is more efficient to shift the decimal point. If you were to format those values using fixed-point notation, they'd use more zeros:

```
>>> format(8.53443431568e-05, '.53f')
'0.00008534434315680000128750276600086976941383909434080'
>>> format(6.8580275751e-07, '.53f')
'0.00000068580275751000002849671038224199648425383202266'
```

*Eventually*, `f` becomes **too small** for the floating point type; floating point values simply can't go closer to zero beyond this point:

```
165.0 5.89639287564e-220
166.0 1.05923225311e-221
167.0 1.89148616627e-223
168.0 3.35766775077e-225
169.0 5.92529603077e-227
170.0 0.0
```

The last value before `0.0` is 5.925 with two hundred and twenty seven zeros before it:

```
>>> format(5.92529603077e-227, '.250f')
'0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000592529603077000028336751'
```

That's pretty close to the absolute minimum value a `float` object can represent; see the [`min` attribute of the `sys.float_info` named tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.float_info):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info.min
2.2250738585072014e-308
```

In other words, you reached the limits, and there was no more representable value between `5.92529603077e-227` and `0.0` left.